# Modify ldap provider url without restarting the spring security application

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-ldap, spring-security-ldap

we are providing facility to customer to configure ldap server runtime. But when i modify provider server url used in constructor of context source, the application crashes. Is there any way to change ldap server url at runtime? for LdapAuthenticationProvider.

Answer (score 0):

If this is a case where you are changing the provider because one may be down for some reason, you should set up multiple authentication providers (`security:authentication-provider`) in your spring-security config file.  Spring-security will start at the top of the list & keep trying until it finds one that works.  That way you can leave this setup & not have a need to redeploy your code.